# Resize the local view in video chat

Tags: android, sinch

How to resize the local view in the video tutorial like the view at the top right,in the tutorial you set the dimensions of the view as 150dp width and 200dp hight, when I tried to change those dimensions the image of the video didn't fit the view there was clipping from both sides, how to change the view dimensions and  make the video image fit it regardless the dimensions (whatever the value of width and hight).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, not at the moment, to avoid clipping use the same aspect ratio for now

Comment: so the aspect ratio I think is 3:4?, and when would I be able to change this?(will you be allowing to change aspect ratio soon?)

Comment: Aspect ration will be in GA most likely. early Jan. if this answered you question do you mind marking is as answered? (I know it was not what you wanted but its correct :))